# Using typeof in Xtend

Tags: xtend

It might be the stupidest question on Xtend. But here it goes

I'm trying to convert the following to Xtend

```
if (obj instanceof Integer) {
    message.reply((Integer)obj);
}
```

I know that I would need to use the `typeof` function.

Can I use `typeof`as a direct replacement to `instanceof`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`typeof` is an old syntax to retrieve the class object. If you're using a newer version of Xtend this is no longer required. Apart from that the `instanceof` syntax is just like in Java but the cast statement is different so you would write:

```
if (obj instanceof Integer) {
    message.reply(obj as Integer)
}
```

Since Xtend 2.5 auto-casting is supported so you can even write:

```
if (obj instanceof Integer) {
    message.reply(obj) // obj is automatically casted to Integer
}
```

Comment: The switch expression also has a nice syntax for automatic type conversion, named "type guards": http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/documentation/203_xtend_expressions.html#type-guards